# Could not create connection to database server' Attempted reconnect 3 times Giving up

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I configured multiple data sources and started running normally. After two hours of not operating the database, I performed an insert operation and encountered a 'Could not create connection to database server' Attempted reconnect 3 times Giving up

I hope he can successfully execute the insert after 8 hours of inactivity

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.